# object-clause for "to feel"

Tags: word-usage, grammar

> The fields of mathematics and statistics, like Bayesian theory, are largely applied to practical application of information and communication technology, which make me no longer feel the math and statistics boring.

This is part of my motivation letter. My questions are:

1,  Is this grammar of this sentence correct : **make sb. feel sth. + adj** ?

2, As for the word "**boring**" in this case, I actually don't want to describe the math and statistics in a negative tone. I just want to express that "math and statistics themselves are not very interesting, but after implementing in the technologies of information and communication, they become interesting".
I also consider to "which make me no longer feel the math and statistics not useful". How do you feel about that?

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! You might want to wait a day or two before choosing an answer :) You may get other useful and interesting answers. But people might not want to write you another answer if you've already chosen one. You can click on the green tick, to 'unselect' my answer, if you want :-)

Comment: @Araucaria If I looked up "warm-hearted SE user" in a dictionary, it'd have your name -- it's not every day you see the author of an answer obliging the answerer *not* to accept it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is really about the verb *FEEL*. Many verbs can take a Direct Object and aso a Predicative Complement describing the Direct Object. Two verbs which can work like this are the verbs *FIND* and *CONSIDER*:

- I consider the Prime Minister an idiot.
- I found the concert boring.

In the first sentence the Direct Object is *the Prime Minister* and the phrase describing the *Prime Minister* is the Predicative Complement *an idiot*. In the second example the Direct Object is *the concert* and the phrase describing the concert is the word *boring*.

The verb *FEEL* doesn't **usually** work this way:

- *I felt the Prime Minister an idiot. (not good)
- *I felt the concert boring. (not good)

For this reason the Original Poster's example is not grammatical:

- [This] makes me no longer feel the math and statistics boring.

However, the verb *FEEL* can take a finite clause as a Complement. The Original Poster could say:

- [This] makes me no longer feel that the math and statistics are boring.

Alternatively they could change the verb they use:

- [This] makes me no longer find the math and statistics so boring.

Answer (score 1):

[feel](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/feel) verb (OPINION)

B1 [I or T] to have a ​particular ​opinion about or ​attitude towards something:

> I feel **that** I should be doing more to ​help her.
>
> He had always felt him​self **to be** ​inferior to his ​brothers.

When you use **feel** in this way, you have to use either **that** + a clause (some words that include a verb), or **to be** followed by an adjective.

Here are two ways of handling the end of your sentence:

> .. which make me no longer feel **that** maths and statistics are boring.
>
> .. which make me no longer feel maths and statistics **to be** boring.

I would favour **that**: the **to be** option sounds a little stuffy.

Regarding ways of avoiding the negatives, how about this:

> ...which sustains my interest in maths and statistics.

Comment: Close, but as a native English speaker I would write "which makes me no longer feel that mathematics and statistics are boring." // I went with mathematics since that was the form first used. I just personally don't like switching between mathematics and math.

Comment: @MaxW: for formal writing, agreed. NGram certainly bears you out from a BrE point of view, but **math** is catching up fast for AmE. I was trying to minimise the changes to that section in order to make the corrected grammar clearer: I did cheekily change math to maths though :-)

Comment: @MaxW,  maths is the BrE colloquialism for mathematics, math is the AmE version. The usage of the colloquialism is much less widely accepted in BrE than AmE.

Comment: But both _math_ and _maths_ are singular.